# Data-URL option on Bootstrap Table adding borders

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-table

On my page, I have two tables made with Bootstrap Table. One of them I've manually input data into the rows and columns and the other populates with `data-toggle="table" data-url="working-url.php"`. They both have the class `table-borderless`, but when the table with the data-url is generated, the class `table-bordered` seems to be added automatically. The other table has no borders, as expected.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

EDIT:
This is my source code:

```
<table data-toggle="table"
  data-url="working-url.php"
  class="table table-borderless table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-2" data-field="statistic">Statistic</th>
      <th scope="col-2" data-field="value">Value of Stat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

But when I load the page and then inspect element, I get this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" 
  data-url="working-url.php" 
  class="table table-borderless table-striped table-bordered table-hover"> 
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: are you able to share HTML for this ? also `table-bordered` will be automatically added if new row is generated. You can remove it manually from the table using jQuery or Javascript. Let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I added the HTML, but if ```table-bordered``` is automatically added for new rows, then I guess I'll just have to manually change it. Ah well. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need help with removing the class manually ? like jQuery or JS help

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that would be great, thank you!

Comment: See my working solution below. Do not forget to up-vote and accept as "the" answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is an efficient way to `removeClass()` from your data which is getting added via bootstrap 4.

You can either use `JS` or `jQuery` for it.

Just run snippet below to see it action. You can add the following JS or jQuery code to your table to removeClass manually which you do not want.

Also, I have added an `ID` to you table called `my_table` this is to make sure that we are only removing class `table-bordered` from one table and not every table on you page - if any

```js
//jQuery//
$('#my_table').removeClass('table-bordered')

//Javascript Version//
var element = document.getElementById("my_table");
element.classList.remove("table-bordered");
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table data-toggle="table" data-url="working-url.php" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-2" data-field="statistic">Statistic</th>
      <th scope="col-2" data-field="value">Value of Stat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.